# Smoothing an LED where switch is at ground side

Tags: led, capacitor, dc

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIVDR3m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch in the circuit is before the resistor (circuit pictured above), I could smooth the LED by placing a capacitor in parallel to the resistor and the LED. Unfortunately, the circuit is as given below and I can only add elements. Is it possible (how?) to buffer that LED with a capacitor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd2fP8m.png)</sup>

Comment: Why would the switch placement matter? Why not just put a capacitor there now, or at least draw the original circuit you mean and understand.

Comment: What do you mean "buffer the LED"?

Comment: I'm not sure if what you mean by buffer means what everyone else means by buffer. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, explaining what problem you have to solve and why then the solution you have and why. Please edit your question, don't add this information in comments. Thanks.

Comment: there is no such thing as `before the resistor` per se

Comment: Tip: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Please edit your question, take out the word 'buffer' and use a correct term :-) It doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: @Transistor: Thanks, I was looking for that!

Comment: @TonyM: English is not my native language. What is the correct term for cushioning against fluctuations?

Comment: I understand. Do you mean 'smoothing'? A capacitor on the output of a bridge rectifier would be called a smoothing capacitor (though some call it 'reservoir' but).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "buffer" you mean to keep the LED on for extra time after the switch is opened then you use the same arrangement. Think: the circuit doesn't know whether you switched off the battery positive or the battery negative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjrnXe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The LED, R and C don't know which side the switch is on.*

The LED will fade out in a time roughly given by τ = R × C.

Comment: I had thought that it would make a difference which pole would be still connected to the R, D, C part of the circuit. I will try to build and test your circuit.

Comment: When the switch is open no current is flowing in that pole of the switch so it is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Works, thanks, up-voted and accepted!